# Replacing JWT token by another JWT token while using an authorizer in HTTP API Gateway

Tags: jwt, aws-api-gateway, lambda-authorizer

In my project, I have presently a legacy authentication that works in such a way:

1. There is a client (standalone) that talks to an `API service` which is a custom application running in a container.
2. A cloud Identity provider (IdP) is used that supports OAuth with PKCE. It provides its token via usual login process when the user goes to a login page and then gets redirected to a callback.
3. `API service`   acts as a recipient for the callback. It, therefore, obtains Identity Provider `token-1` and stores it in a cache. Based on this it returns to the client a modified `token-2` "computed" from `token-1` but different.
4. Once the client needs to make a REST call, it decorates it with the `token-2` JWT token. The call goes to the API service that matches it to `token-1` which can be then validated against IdP.

I have a need to get rid of the `API service` with cloud-native mechanisms. I assume that AWS HTTP API gateway can be integrated with IdP directly using its [JWT Authorizer capability](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-jwt-authorizer.html).  Regretfully I can not affect the current legacy flow that must remain functional.

However, I would like to insert a Lambda between the JWT Authorizer and client endpoints which would be doing the exchange of client-facing tokens to IdP tokens (doing what `API service` was doing). Would that be possible and how I can approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to create a Lambda Authorizer (Formally known as Custom Authorizer) instead of using the default JWT Authorizer.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-lambda-authorizer.html

You can write your own logic in this including validating tokens and performing additional steps like you mentioned.